# Don't want to receive LinkedIn connections request from outside of my country

Tags: linkedin

I don't like such kind of social media webpages which are open for everyone to view your information. I am here on "LinkedIn" just to have connections with different employers. Since I receive many connection requests from my friends or people outside my country, which I do not like. I want a method which allow me not to receive connection requests from people outside my country. Is it possible?
Can I also block people from outside my country to show my profile?

Answer (score 2):

See this to [Controlling Who Can Send You Invitations](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/70/~/controlling-who-can-send-you-invitations).

> Select one of the following preferences:
>
> 1. Anyone on LinkedIn (Recommended)
> 2. Only people who know your email address or appear in your "Imported Contacts" list
> 3. Only people who appear in your "Imported Contacts" list
>
> Note: If you select one of the last two options above, go to the [Add Connections](https://www.linkedin.com/fetch/importAndInvite) page to make sure your **Imported Contacts** list is up to date.

In your case select the third option and up to date your imported list with your country people.

---

[Blocking or Unblocking a Member](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/47081/~/blocking-or-unblocking-a-member)

To block a member from viewing your profile:

> 1. Go to the profile of the person you'd like to block.
>
>    - **Note:** After you block someone, you will disappear from the Who's Viewed Your Profile section of the person you blocked.
> 2. Move your cursor over the down arrow next to the button in the top section of the member's profile and select **Block or report** from the list.
> 3. Check the box next to **Block**.
> 4. Click **Continue**.
> 5. On the next screen, click **Agree** to confirm your action.
>
>    - **Note:** We currently don't offer the ability to block members from your mobile device. Follow the steps above to block a member from your desktop.

Comment: It seems to be the only solution. But I want to have my profile open for all people just on my country. Can I import on the list ( all people who lives in X country can send me connection request) ? or (all people who lives in X country can show my profile) !!

Comment: You might want to set up a filter in your email so that all LinkedIn messages from a domain outside your country get automatically deleted.

Comment: Now it is 2020, and still Linkedin hasn't any option for this purpose. I want to keep my profile open only for EU/North America; it frustrates to go through tons of irrelevant contact requests only to check if there is someone genuine among them.